# How to write shell script to wget a url once, then wget a second url every two minutes for 1 hour

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, wget

I'm new to shell scripting.

I'm trying to somehow cron a job that will wget one url once to trigger a task, and another url every 2 minutes after to keep the task alive.

So far I've managed to get the first url to work without issue, the problem comes with the second url wget repeating every 2 minutes for 1 hour.

I've tried including cron within the .sh script as I saw suggested somewhere else, like

```
*/2 * * * * wget $url
```

but terminal just throws it out with an error "no such file or directory".

Whats the best method of doing this?

Comment: Do you put this line `*/2 * * * * wget $url` directly into your script? That isn't going to work, this has to be put in the crontab file.

Comment: Yes I did. How can I do this in a .sh file?

Comment: How about using a loop counting from 1 to 30 and then `sleep` for 120s between every `wget`-run? Not exactly 1 hour, but I assume the `wget` runs only for a few seconds.

Comment: How do I go about creating a loop with a sleep after every run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fiximan and @steeldriver suggested, another option is to run `wget` in a loop for 1 hour:

```
COUNT=0
while [ $COUNT -lt 30 ]; do
  wget $url
  sleep 120
  COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))
done
```

Note that script containing this code must be run using `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: ... it looks like it would run fine in any POSIX shell actually

Answer (score 1):

In a script file (.sh) you can make a loop that will run for 1 hour (3600 seconds) with a 2 minute pause (120 seconds).

```
# Initialize seconds variable
seconds=0
# Loop until 1 hour is done
while [[ $seconds < 3600 ]]; do
    seconds="$(($seconds + 120))"
    sleep 120
    wget $url
done
```

*I put the `wget` command as the last thing it runs so that it doesn't wait the additional 2 minutes after running the last `wget` command.*

Answer (score 0):

The line `*/2 * * * * wget $url` should be put into your crontab to make it work. You should first output your current crontab, append the line to it and install it as a new crontab.

It can be done eg. using the following commands:

```
crontab -l >/tmp/cronfile
echo "*/2 * * * * wget $url" >>/tmp/cronfile
crontab /tmp/cronfile
```

The first command can output "no crontab for *username*" on stderr if there is no crontab currently defined, to avoid this you may redirect stderr to `/dev/null` like this:

```
crontab -l >/tmp/cronfile 2>/dev/null
```

Be aware that running the above lines will cause the `wget` operation repeat **forever** ie. until you remove it manually from crontab. If you want it to be removed automatically after 1 hour, you have to create an `at` job that will remove `wget` from your crontab after 1 hour:

```
at now +1hour <<EOF
crontab -l | grep -v wget | crontab -
EOF
```